# Не устанавливается правильный пользователь для сокета mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache2, mod-wsgi

На апаче крутится несколько виртуальных хостов, один из которых принадлежит другому пользователю. Когда-то давно я включал ему `mod_wsgi` и всё прекрасно работал, потом выключал за ненадобностью, а сейчас включил — не работает. В логах такая ошибка:

> Permission denied: … Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process 'foo' on '/run/apache2/wsgi.17884.0.2.sock'

Этот сокет принадлежит пользователю `www-data`, а процесс этого виртуального хоста честно работает от `username`. Собственно, сейчас временный костыль — делаю `chmod username /run/apache2/wsgi.[0-9].0.2.sock` после каждого перезапуска, и всё работает нормально до следующего перезапуска, но это не катит. Почему пользователь перестал назначаться автоматически?

Гугл советовал:

- переназначить `WSGISocketPrefix` — не помогло, все сокеты так и принадлежат `www-data`;
- удалить `apache2-mpm-prefork` — но пакет этот не установлен вовсе, а модуль `mpm_prefork` включен и находится в зависимостях от `mpm_itk`, поэтому я оба отключить не могу.

**Конфиг виртуального хоста:**

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:11000>
  AssignUserID username username
  WSGIDaemonProcess foo user=username group=username
  WsgiProcessGroup foo
  WSGIScriptAlias …
  …
</VirtualHost>
```

`apache2.conf` стандартный для **Debian 8** (но всё сломалось ещё на **Debian 7**, так что ни обновление, ни этот файл ни при чём).

Включенные модули (наверняка много лишнего и наверняка отключил что-то нужное?):

```
access_compat    authn_core       authz_groupfile  autoindex        dir              mime             negotiation      rewrite          ssl
alias            authn_file       authz_host       cgi              env              mpm_itk          php5             setenvif         status
auth_basic       authz_core       authz_user       deflate          filter           mpm_prefork      reqtimeout       socache_shmcb    wsgi
```

Comment: Проблема всё ещё актуальна — временный костыль до сих пор стабильно костыляет каждую полночь.))

Comment: Ладно, я наконец-то перевёл все свои проекты с mod_wsgi на gunicorn, так что теперь проблема не очень актуальна.)